# ROC curve sklearn probabilities vs. scores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I don't understand how to interpret the output of `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(x, y)` when my y are prediction labels and not probability scores.

Here's the simplified code example:

```py
true = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
predict = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(truth, predict)

>>> fpr
Output: array([0.        , 0.33333333, 1.        ])

>>> tpr
Output: array([0.  , 0.75, 1.  ])

>>> threshold
Output: array([2, 1, 0])
```

I don't understand how to interpret this output for `tpr`, `fpr` and `threshold`. I mean I understand what the output is but I don't understand how to interpret three values for each False Positive Rate, True Positive Rate and Threshold.

Also when I use probability scores:

```py
truth = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
scores = [0.2, 0.78, 0.95, 0.65, 0.33, 0.73, 0.34]

fpr_score, tpr_score, threshold_score = roc_curve(truth, scores)

>>> fpr_score
Ouput: array([0.        , 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 1.        , 1.        ])

>>> tpr_score
Output: array([0.  , 0.  , 0.75, 0.75, 1.  ])

>>> threshold
Output: array([1.95, 0.95, 0.65, 0.33, 0.2 ])
```

Here I get different values in the output, and this time it has a better resolution. Can anyone explain how to interpret values in both the scenario?

My main goal is to adjust threshold to obtain high AUC score, and so I need to set a class prediction as Positive or Negative depending upon threshold selection, but that implies I will be using class labels for `y` and so I will only have three values for each FPR, TPR and Threshold.

Comment: You should be using probability as your input and not prediction labels when calling `roc_curve()` . The outputs are essentially, False Positive Rate, True Positive Rate for respective thresholds.

Comment: Yes, I know the output is False Positive Rate, True Positive Rate and Threshold, but when I use labels, I only get three values in each output, so I am trying to understand what they mean and how to interpret them for FPR, TPR and Threshold?

Comment: Check the docs of [`roc_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)

The inputs are `y_true` and `y_score`, with `y_score` being your **target scores** and not your **target predictions**. Hence your first code is erroneous.